# Joomla module appearing on virtuemart all product category views

Tags: module, joomla3.0, categories, virtuemart

A module containing text is appearing on all sub-category and product pages rather than just the top-level category page.

Joomla 3.9.2,
Virtuemart 3.4.2

I recently underwent some major updates for my Joomla website and extensions. I have a module containing some text which appears on my Products webpage, which is a view of the two top level product categories.

Since all the updates, this module is now appearing on sub-category view pages and all individual product pages as well. The module assignment will only allow me to either select or deselect the main 'Products' page. I have tried looking at the settings for my product categories and products, but nothing has come to light.

Worth noting that I don't have a very extensive knowledge of Joomla, as the website wasn't built by me.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is a general Joomla feature, the modules of the sub-categories are inherited from the top categories.

To solve your problem you can add menu items for the top categories and menu items for the sub categories. That might be in a visible or hidden menu.

Now you can choose to display the module in the top category but not in the sub-categories. In tab "menu assignment" of the module choose only the top category.